# Raspistill preview window invisible

Tags: pi-3, raspicam

A couple of months ago, I had a good installation of the raspberry pi, and the picam module I was using was working great. Recently, one of my raspi's drivers got corrupted, so I had to re-install the OS. After I finished setting up the picam, I tried to preview it, but nothing came up on my screen. (I am using SSH,VNC, and Camera) but i'm trying to preview from the raspi. (no remote connection) However, when I run the command, the red light on my picam turns on for a second, but nothing pops up on screen.
I am going to do an april fools prank involving motion detection, so I need to fix this ASAP.
Thanks!

Comment: make sure your using the right arguments. try `raspistill -f -t 10` or `raspivid -f -t 10` to display fullscreen for 10 seconds.

Comment: I did use those commands, I also tried raspistill -fp and raspistill -o test.jpg. Since i've tried detaching and reattaching the sunny chip, any command I do that is camera related waits for a few seconds, then says something about `failed to enable enospc`.I ran the debugger and it said `Dump_Stack failed`. Do I need to replace my camera? All I did to the sunny chip was to detach it and reattach it.